# Read Extras from Intent MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera-intent

1) If I try to pass extra data to `Intent` to another activity like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, NoteActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(LIFE_ENTRY_NOTE, mEntry.getNote());
intent.putExtra(LIFE_ENTRY_ID, mEntry.get_ID());
```

Then it works fine and I am able to read this via `data.getExtras().getString(CubbieButton.LIFE_ENTRY_NOTE)`

2) But if I create intent like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(LIFE_ENTRY_ID, mEntry.get_ID());
```

I am NOT able to read it via `data.getExtras().getString(CubbieButton.LIFE_ENTRY_NOTE)`

All readings done in `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)`

Is there any limitation that I am not able to carry data with Intent created via  `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When onActivityResult is called, "data" is likely a new intent created by the activity that you called. Since you called the camera to start, it does not know about your LIFE_ENTRY values and most likely ignores them. As opposed to your NoteActivity class which you know how to handle those values and can save them/pass them back to the calling activity.

Comment: So If my understanding is correct there is no way to pass such a data to camera intent and then back to the caller activity, right ?

Comment: Correct. It is up to the activity that you call what to do with the data you pass it. In the case of the android camera, it simply doesn't know what to do with your data (rather, it doesn't even know it's there since it doesn't check) so it ignores it.  Is it possible you can store the values in a bundle when you call the startActivityForResult and then restore the values when you resume?

Comment: Thank you for respond. Bundle looks like feasible way. I will double-check it and put comment here.

Comment: trying to pass some data the same way, have you figured out a solution ? thanks